# Independence of components of random vectors

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

If I have four random variables $X_1, X_2, Y_1, Y_2$ such that $X_i \perp Yj$ for $i,j \in \left\{{1,2}\right\}$, $X_1 \perp X_2$, $Y_1 \perp Y_2$, it could be say that $\mathbb{E}[X_1X_2Y_1Y_2]=\mathbb{E}[X_1]\mathbb{E}[X_2]\mathbb{E}[Y_1]\mathbb{E}[Y_2]$

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 3):

No, sadly. You need joint independence, not only pairwise.

Take $X_1,X_2,Y_1$ to be (jointly) independent Rademacher random variables (i.e., uniform on $\{-1,1\}$), and set $Y_2=X_1X_2Y_1$. Then $X_1,X_2,Y_1,Y_2$ satisfy the assumptions, but...

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but how is $Y_2$ independent on $X_1$ in your example? If they were, something like $P(Y_2< -0.5|X_1=0) = P(Y_2<  -0.5)$ should be true, when it's obviously false. But again, I might be missing something.

Comment: $X_1$ is uniform on $\{-1,1\}$ (i.e., two elements, *not* the interval). (all the random variables here can only take values $-1$ and $1$). You can check that you indeed have the pairwise independence.

Comment: Oh great, I was being sloppy and didn't notice that's not an interval. Great example. At least I was right in my first sentence!